# Using session variables on other pages

Tags: php, wordpress, session

This question might be a bit stupid but I am only starting my adventure with sessions - didn't need to use them before. On the homepage I have a session which stores all the variables properly, that's no problem.

When I go to a sub-page under the same domain and try to call the variables from session, I just get empty fields. I tried doing print_r($_REQUEST); on the sub-page and it prints out the following:

```
Array ( [wp-settings-1] => libraryContent=browse&editor=html [wp-settings-time-1] => 1478015951 [PHPSESSID] => 0744bf21ab3712e4735e07d926433aa3 [sec_session_id] => 60e56049f51c76e9ec4932c6702e7b72 )
```

Which matches the output on the homepage. I know I should do a session_start(); but when I include that in my code I get the following error:

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
```

The reason I know that the variables are not being passed is because when I do

```
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
}

echo "User id: " .$_SESSION["user_id"];
```

I only get

```
User id:
```

And whenever I try to call the variable I get an error that it is not set.

Is there a step that I am missing?

Setting the session variables:

```
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 
        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked 
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches 
            // the password the user submitted.
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $sessions['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                // Login successful. 
                return true;
            } else {
                // Password is not correct 
                // We record this attempt in the database 
                $now = time();
                if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) 
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: login_attempts");
                    exit();
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // No user exists. 
        return false;
```

And the function to start secure session:

```
function sec_session_start() {
$session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name 
$secure = SECURE;

// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;

// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}

// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);

// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);

session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Comment: where you are setting user_id in to sessions? if it is wordpress use global $session;print_r($sessions); it will print your session variable. to set user_id into sessions---$sessions['user_id']='your user id'; that you can access anywhere in the application

Comment: No I am setting the user_id in php session when logging in to the platform, nothing to do with wordpress
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

Answer (score 0):

By seeing you code i understand it is wordpress site,

if yes follow following steps:

step1: add following code into your wp-content/themes-folder/functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

step 2: set user_id

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = "your id";
```

step 3: to access your session id

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $value = $_SESSION['myKey'];
} else {
    $value = '';
}
```

if your site is not a wordpress

```
add session_start() at header.php(or first line of your code)
then use your session variables.
```

Comment: It's not a wordpress site. It's a php website, the wordpress session is there possibly because there is a wordpress installation on the server but has nothing to do with the actual site that I am working with atm Please see my edited question to see how I am setting and starting session

Comment: And adding session_start(); at the start of the file throws an error saying that there is a session already running